# Defaults to git push

Tags: git

I do push to two remote repositories when I do  `git commit all`

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:kkk_pro/tst1.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "all"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:kkk_pro/tst2.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/all/*
        pushurl = git@bitbucket.org:kkk_pro/tst1.git
        pushurl = git@bitbucket.org:kkk_pro/tst2.git
```

But when I type `git push` git pushes only to `tst1` ? Why? How to ask git to use `all` as default remote?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I type git push git pushes only to tst1

---

#### How does git decide where to push the code?

Prior to [Git version 2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt) everytime you ececuted `git push` without specifiying remote **all your local** branches have been pushed to the remote.

Starting in [git v2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt) you need to specify the origin and the remote whenever you pushed.

Whenever you type `git push` without remote & branch git will push the branch to the default upstream branch.

You can set the default branch on the remote for the push using:

```
git push --set-upstream <origin> <branch>
```

[image]

From your config:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
```

You can see that your master is set to be pushed to `origin` whih is `tst1`

#### How to add multiple push urls?

```
git remote set-url --add --push <origin_name> git@github.com:.../a.git
git remote set-url --add --push <origin_name> git@github.com:.../b.git
```

#### How to view the configuration?

```
git remote show origin
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

origin is the default remote, just move it there.

From the docs:

When the command line does not specify where to push with the  argument, branch.*.remote configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to origin.